# How do I replace "%26" in filename?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I'm saving scraped images with:

```
img_url = agent.page.at(".field-content a")[:href]
root_img_url = URI.join(page_url,img_url).to_s
cover = File.basename(root_img_url)
file = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'assets', 'images', cover), 'wb') { |f|
    f.write(open(root_img_url).read)
}
```

Some of the images have a `%26` in the name, like `cover_b%26w_xyz_.jpg`, and when I save them in my database, and want to see them in my index view, they do not appear, but are still saved in the assets/images folder.

How can I replace the `%26` character before I save the file `cover` in the database?

Comment: The filename doesn't appear in the index view, or the & doesn't appear in the filename?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%26` is a URL-encoded `&` so you could use [`URI.decoded`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-decode):

```
cover = File.basename(URI.decode(root_img_url))
# cover is now 'cover_b&w_xyz_.jpg'
```

Comment: @mu_is_too_short this work to convert the %26 to &, and in consequence the images appears. Thank you. I have a new question... how manage the images with blank spaces between characters, like "cover xyz_.jpg"?

Comment: You'd usually URI encode the filenames when they go back into HTML, that should take care of spaces.

Comment: The file name i try to read look is: "Responsive'13 #02 Cover DOTS_0.jpg". I use URI::encode to print the name in the database cover, but, the "'" still there.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why is `'` a problem?

Comment: I can't show the "Responsive'13 #02 Cover DOTS_0.jpg" image in my view.

Comment: Maybe you should ask another question which includes the offending file name and what your view code looks like.